# React state shows null when calling from an onClick handler on a button through a dynamic generated component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm trying to create a simple admin panel to add questions to a Quiz app.
When generating questions, I've a simple snippet thats adds a React component as follows.

```
const textQuestion: ReactElement = (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Col span={16}>
          <Form.Item
            name={`question${renderTextQuestions.length - 1}`}
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Enter question" }]}
          >
            <TextArea placeholder="Enter Question" rows={5} />
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <div className="button-section">
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                removeQuestion(renderTextQuestions.length);
              }}
              Icon={<DeleteIcon />}
              label="Remove Question"
            />
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={24}>
          <Form.Item>
            <Input
              type="hidden"
              name={`answerSelectionType${renderTextQuestions.length - 1}`}
            />
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Form.Item
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Answer cannnot be empty" }]}
            name={`question${
              renderTextQuestions.length - 1
            }_answer${++answerCounter}`}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Answer cannnot be empty" }]}
            name={`question${
              renderTextQuestions.length - 1
            }_answer${++answerCounter}`}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Answer cannnot be empty" }]}
            name={`question${
              renderTextQuestions.length - 1
            }_answer${++answerCounter}`}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Answer cannnot be empty" }]}
            name={`question${
              renderTextQuestions.length - 1
            }_answer${++answerCounter}`}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
```

This is called from a function as follows

```
const addTextBasedQuestion = () => {
    answerCounter = 0;
    setRenderTextQuestions((prevState) => [...prevState, textQuestion]);
  };
```

and this is the main render method

```
 return (
    <div className="quiz-admin-container">
      <Form form={formRef}>
        {renderTextQuestions}
        <Button label="Submit" onClick={handleFormSubmit} />
      </Form>
      <Button onClick={addTextBasedQuestion} label="Add Text Question" />
      <Button onClick={addPictureBasedQuestion} label="Add Picture Question" />
    </div>
  );
```

The problem is that when I click on the button that calls `removeQuestion()` method, and log the questions state variable `renderTextQuestions` it shows an empty array. But when I add another question then it shows only `1 element` in the array which was the second question added.

Can anyone help me understand what's happening here? Why does the removeQuestion function show empty state.

Although it only does that when I call it from the onClick handler inside `button-secion` div but works fine when called from the main `render` method.

Comment: Please add the code for your state and the implementation of renderTextQuestions  . Also  IMHO your `textQuestion` should be a Component of its own . Instead of having some JSX assigned to a variable .

Comment: Let me update the question with that snippet then

Comment: @Shyam I've added the update.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a good approach, the better and the right approach is that you save only the info of the questions inside the `renderTextQuestions` and then map this array like this

```
renderTextQuestions.map(question => (
   YOUR-JSX
)
```

but you put your whole jsx inside the array which I strongly recommend not to do that, just imagine you have 20 questions then you would end up having a super big state